# Bootstrap 2 columns right column covering background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website and I use bootstrap.
I have 2 columns in the left one I have some text with a pattern as background and in the right one I want a `background-image` covering the entire column.

For some reason my background image is not showing. I've tried some things but the image never covers the entire column

here's a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNNQrQ) to demonstrate

Comment: Hi Frank, Could you please post your HTML/CSS code to help us figuring the issue, Thanks!

Comment: @PeterWilson I did, you can use the codepin link in OP, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not related to the background image itself, it related to the height of the right column it's height is just `1px` because Boostrap by default give each column `min-height:1px;` when it doesn't have any contents

So you have to give it some content or height of `426px` like the left column

Now you have many options to fix this

**Option 1**

using jQuery:

```
function adjusting_height(){
  var height = $('.has-content').css('height');
  $('.has-image div').css('height',height);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  adjusting_height();
$(window).resize(function(){
  adjusting_height();
})

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-full">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="has-content text-center col-md-6 nopadding">
      <div class="block give-me-a-pattern-please-thanks">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>Hello there, I am a paragraph text. It's nice to meet you! Unfortunately I am here only temporarily, but hey don't be sad! I am sure we'll meet again soon. Oh yeah before you move on don't forget the check me out on mobile devices I look awesome
      there as well.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
<div class="has-image text-center col-md-6 nopadding">
  <div style="background-image: url(http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/12/09/butterfly-wallpaper_093549561_256.jpeg);"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-full{
margin: 0 5%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.block{
padding: 100px;
color: #666;
}

.block hr{
margin-top: 40px !important;
margin-bottom: 40px !important;
border-top: 3px solid aqua !important;
width: 15% !important;
}

.nopadding {
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
}

.give-me-a-pattern-please-thanks{
background-image: url("http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/new_year_background.png") !important;
background-size: cover;
}
```

See the new [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/w34/pen/ZWWgNX)  you should find it like 
 [image]
**Note** 
you have a wrong selector in CSS you had used `nopadding` it should be `.nopadding`

**option 2**

it not good idea but it will solve it

You can add the same content to the column on the right but give it `opacity:0;`

Comment: If I give it a fixed height would it still be responsive? Will it scale on all devices?

Comment: @FrankLucas No because on small screens the content will take much more height :(

Comment: So how can I fix this problem? I've tried using height: auto but doesn't seem to work

Comment: So basically you've added only the has-image class and the javascript? That doesnt seem to fix the problem for me, unfortunately

Comment: @FrankLucas seems that you didn't checked the new codepen and jquery code and edits made to the CSS :( , please read the answer again and check the codepen http://codepen.io/w34/pen/ZWWgNX

Comment: I did my friend, in the codepen it doesn't seem to work as well

Comment: @FrankLucas could you please send me the link of codepen you are checking, and I updated my answer with screenshot from the working codepen

Comment: Yeah but try making your screen smaller (mimic mobile device) the image doesn't cover the entire div in height

Comment: The solution of jQuery is has effect on the loading so try to make your screen smaller then reload the page and it will work anyway I can make to change on window size changing if you want

Comment: Yeah that would be awesome! That is exactly what I need

Comment: @FrankLucas done!, I updated my answer and also my codepen for you

Comment: okay thanks, seems to work only issue I have is that I want the image to centered now the image starts from the left top corner. It this something that can be easily fixed?

Comment: @FrankLucas just add `.has-image div {
    background-position: center center;
}` to your css